# Extracting name of symbol (variable name) from within a function not working

Tags: function-construction, hold, symbols, attributes

**Abstract:** I use a pattern so often that I needed to make a function for constructing it. A function `getName[...]` for extracting name of variable and value only works when defined globally but does not work if called from another function or even if defined from within a function.

**Question:** Can this be fixed? If possible the `makeRow1[...]` is my preferred type of solution.

**About the Code:** the code below shows 3 different contexts/uses for defining `getNamne[...]`. Only the globally defined works.

```
Clear[var]
var = 123; separator = " \[Rule] ";

(* define function in global scope *)
SetAttributes[getName, HoldFirst];
getName[symbol_] := SymbolName[Unevaluated@symbol];
Row[{getName[var], separator, TraditionalForm[var]}]

(* use from within another function *)
makeRow1[var_, separator_ : " \[Rule]"] := 
 Row[{getName[var], separator, TraditionalForm[var]}]
makeRow1[var]

(* define and use within a function *)
makeRow2[var_, separator_ : " \[Rule]"] := Block[{getName},
   SetAttributes[getName, HoldFirst];
   getName[symbol_] := SymbolName[Unevaluated@symbol];
   Row[{getName[var], separator, TraditionalForm[var]}]
   ];
makeRow2[var]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outer function needs to hold also:

```
SetAttributes[{makeRow1, makeRow2}, HoldFirst]

test = 1;

makeRow1[test, " : "]
makeRow2[test, " ~ "]
```

> ```
> test : 1
> test ~ 1
> ```